# Gesture recogniser on top of another view/ button swift 3

Tags: swift

I have a view2 on top of the default uiview and I had like to add a button on top of the view2 with gesture recogniser.

I have set isUserInteractable to true and set a delegate but no luck.

Although guestures are recognised on view2 any button or view I add on top of view 2 isn't recognising guestures or targets.

Hope I make sense.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Please add your code snippet so that you can get appropriate answer for that. Your question is still unclear.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit hard to understand root problem from your Q, but ... could you please check this links ?

[Handling UIKit Gestures](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/handling_uikit_gestures)

[Understanding cocoa and cocoa touch responder chain](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/understanding-cocoa-and-cocoa-touch-responder-chain-12fe558ebe97)

Comment: I have had a look I don't see what's wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0):

I can't add photos because am new to the forum.

I am doing this programmatically.

I have constructed a view with a button on top of it. The view is visible and so as the button.

ATM the button is not recognising any gestures or targets I add to it.

I have constructed the button with lazy var as well so it should allow targets or guestures.

The problem is nothing I add to view2 is been recognised when tapped?

Comment: Ok. Have you added view2 and button on view in storyboard or programmatically?

Comment: Is all constructed programmatically.

Comment: Check your parent view's user interaction whether it is enabled or not. Because if your parent view has no user interaction then its subview does have any interaction too.

Comment: Am not using storyboard at all.

Comment: Thanks!!!!!! That resolved the problem. I enabled user interaction on all the parent views and the button is now been recognised.

Comment: Great ;) 
My pleasure ^_^
Happy Coding :)